# Obfuscar tool ForceStringHiding

Tags: settings, obfuscar

After hours finally got why my app crashes after obfuscating by Obfuscar. That is StringHiding in MyClass. So settings for module now is

```
    <SkipStringHiding type="Myspacename.MyClass" name="*" />
```

Now I need to hide only some of the strings inside MyClass. For example

```
private const string TrialLicenseKey = "AEAF3-N4C7K-BWDTV-3CLZB-XXXXX";
```

I was trying some combinatons of settings, but strings are still visible in Reflector.

Comment: A trial key should not be a secret. Meanwhile string obfuscation is reversible by definition, and you should be aware of that.

Comment: I know public/private keys tech, trial key is for example. How force some string obfuscation?

Answer (score 0):

Is ForceStringHiding supported? What is for name parameter? String content, var name, etc.?

```
<ForceStringHiding type="Myspacename.MyClass" name="???" />
```

Comment: Found vars init in constructor

static Debugging()
{
    A = new object();
    c = "AEAF3-N4C7K-BWDTV-3CLZB-XXXX";
    __public = "AOMR0rFgbQxySAHrBpU3N8RF1i3rXkgSC79aXEgE=";
}

Comment: C# compiler rips the const out so Obfuscar cannot process it. You might switch to static read only and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Can't get why i see unobfuscated private static strings in Reflector

```
static Debugging() 
{
A = new object();
__public = "AOMRDQELD+0rFgbQxySAHrBpU3N8RF1i3rXkgSC79aXEgE=";
D = "ActivationHardwareId";
d = "LicenseKey";
E = "ActivationKey";
... 
}
```

settings for Obfuscar

```
  <Var name="KeepPublicApi" value="true" />
  <Var name="HidePrivateApi" value="true" />
  <Var namr="HideStrings" value="true" />
```